# Intellij vcs plugin, view changed files AND file changes in the same window

Tags: intellij-idea

I normally do `git diff` for this but want to leverage the intellij gui.

The Version Control tab just shows me all the files that changed:
[image]

To view the actual changes I have to select a file and choose "Show Diff".

This opens another window. Now from this other window if I want to see changes for another file I have to click this button then open the other file:

[image]

I don't like that. Is there a way to have this in the same pane? Where on the left I see a list of the changed files and I just have to select the file to see its changes? Otherwise its very clunky and unusable for being able to see a tree of changed files and selecting the one's changes I want to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it, I wanted "preview diff"

[image]